# How to configure Oracle OpenSSO Fedlet with multiple service providers in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, single-sign-on, federation, opensso

We have an application (service provider) which is already set up to use SSO. The user is authenticated using an identity provider and IDP sends the request to the service provider with a few attributes which are retrieved and used at the service provider app for creating a session.

Now we need to create one more service provider (app2) which should be authenticated by the same identity provider. The new app2 users should not be having access to view app1. The users can be differentiated with an attribute which will be contained in the IDP request.

My question is how to configure the new SP in the IDP site using the Oracle OpenSSO Fedlet SP initiated SSO, and how can the users be restricted on IDP or SP?

Please advise and let me know the procedure to implement the process.

Thank you